# Suppose a die is rolled $14$ times, and $X$ be the number of faces that appear exactly 2 times. How can I find $E(X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It seems that this question is relatively straightforward as it resembles the binomial. However, I cannot complete the entire argument if I try to do it in accordance with $X=0$, $X=1$, and so on and then compute the probability of each. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using bionomial distribution to solve this question.

$p(\text{particular face}) = \frac{1}{6}$

$q(\text{Not particular face}) = 1 - \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$

Now according to bionamial distribution

$P(X=r) = C(n,r) (q)^{n-r} (p)^r$

n is the number of dice. And X is particular result.

Here X = 2 and n = 14.

$P(X=2) = C(14,2) * \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12} * \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2$

And exactly 6 pairs. So,

= $6 * C(14,2) * \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12} * \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2$

Comment: @msm Those numbers are closely related. See my comment below. The $X_i$ are special random variables. Their expectation is equal to the probability that they are $1$

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply the probability that some face occurs exactly twice (which can be calculated with the binomial distribution) with $6$, the number of faces. Here, we use that expectations are additive : $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$

Comment: I'm a bit confused which part you are utilizing that expectations are additive, what part is using the sum of expectations? Thanks!

Comment: OK. I make it a bit clearer : Define $X_1=1$ , if face $1$ occurs exactly twice and $0$ otherwise. Analogue define $X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6$. Now, we are interested in the expectation of $S:=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5+X_6$ which is the number of faces occuring exactly tiwce. Now, we have $E(X_1)=p$ , where $p$ is the probability that face $1$ occurs exactly twice. Of course, the other variables have expectation $p$ as well, so the expectation of $S$ is $6p$

Comment: @msm This solution is correct, see Peter's comment.

Comment: @Dominik Yes, the new revision of the comment seems fine to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

The probability $p$ that any given value, e.g., $6$, appears exactly $2$ times is given by 
$$p={14\choose 2}\cdot\left({1\over6}\right)^2\cdot\left({5\over6}\right)^{12}\ .$$
The expected number $E$ of  values appearing exactly two times is therefore given by
$$E=6p={2685546875\over2176782336}\doteq1.23372\ .$$

Comment: @msm: I think I answered the question of the OP, using linearity of expectation.